# Strategies for a number-guessing game

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Suppose Alice, Bob and Carol are playing a number guessing game, in which Alice, Bob and Carol pick a number from $[0, 1]$ *sequentially* i.e. first Alice then Bob and then Carol. After that, a random number $X$ is drawn from the uniform distribution $U[0, 1]$, and the person whose number is closest to $X$ wins (in terms of absolute differences). Suppose all the three players are smart and want to win, then which number should Alice pick?

An obvious choice seems to be $0.5$, and we can indeed prove that in this case Bob and Carol will have to both pick $0.5$ also - let's say Bob pick any $a<0.5$, then Carol would just pick any $b>0.5$ such that $|b-0.5|<|a-0.5|$ to have a strictly greater probability to win than Bob, which implies Bob wouldn't pick any number other than $0.5$, and thus Carol also has to pick $0.5$ too. So, Alice picking $0.5$ will definitely result in a draw.

My question is, does there exist other choices that can give Alice a strict advantage over Bob and Carol?

Comment: What I do not understand. If a person chooses a number that has been selected before, this person cannot win anymore. Or does a draw mean that all persons win having the same distance ?

Comment: What, if Alice chooses a number different from $0.5$ , isn't Bob's best choice then $0.5$ , which would mean a disadvantage for Alice ?

Comment: @Peter if say Alice chooses 0.3 and Bob chooses 0.5, Carol can choose say 0.50001 and to have an edge. So Bob won't choose 0.5.

Comment: And what would you choose if you were Bob ? Which choice would be better ?

Comment: @Peter you may think of it like this: if two persons have the same distance and they both win then they both win half the award, similarly for three persons with same distances.

Comment: @Peter that's not a trivial question, I need to have some time to think about it. But now I'm on a subway train.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick the closest number game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840442/pick-the-closest-number-game)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that draws are prohibited, but infinitesimals (suggestively named $\epsilon$ here) can be used as tie-breakers.

Carol can always enforce a winning probability $\ge \frac14$: If Alice and Bob pick $0<x<y<1$, then Carol can pick $x-\epsilon$ or $y+\epsilon$ or any number in $(x,y)$ to win with probabilities $\approx x$, $\approx 1-y$, or $\frac{y-x}2$, respectively. At least one of these  is $\ge\frac14$.

Wlog Alice picks $a\le \frac12$.
If Bob picks $b<a$, then Carol can maximize her winning probability by picking $a+\epsilon$. This results in Alice winning with probability $\approx \frac{a-b}2$, Bob with probability $\approx\frac{a+b}2$, and Carol with probability $\approx 1-a$. This also implies that Bob will take $b=a-\epsilon$ to win with probability $\approx a$, i.e., Alice will win with probability $\approx 0$. Bad idea.

Alice must try to convince Bob to pick $b>a$.

Assume Alice picks $\frac 14<a<\frac12$. Then if Bob picks $b=1-a+\epsilon$, Carol will choose between $c=a-\epsilon'$ to win with $\approx a$, or $c=b+\epsilon'$ to win with $\approx a-\epsilon<a$, or $a<c<b$ to win with $\frac{b-a}2=\frac{1-\epsilon}2-a<a$. So she will choose the first option, leading to Alice winning with $\approx\frac{b-a}2\approx \frac12-a$, Bob with $\approx\frac12$, Carol with $\approx a$. Any other choice by Bob will only decrease his chances. Apparently Alice wants to minimize $a$ and should pick $a=\frac14+\epsilon$ in this scenario. As Bob wins $\approx \frac12$, he will indeed happily comply and not pick $b<a$.

If Alice picks $a<\frac14$, Bob can pick $b=\frac{a+2}3$, which will guarantee that Bob gets *at least* $\frac{1-a}3$. However, by allowing Carol to find her optimum in $(a,b)$, the winning probabilities of Bob (and Alice) are not guaranteed to be a specific value. Rather, they depend on a choice by Carol that is indifferent to her (Carol's) result. Alice is only guaranteed to win with at least $a$, but it could be higher. However, Bob might enter a coalition and *promise* to pick $b$ in a way that makes Alice's chance $>\frac14$ if Carol plays optimally. To this end, Bob must make $1-b>\frac{b-a}2$ (to lure Carol into picking $b+\epsilon$) and  $\frac{a+b}2>\frac14$(to keep his promise). So $\frac{2+a}3>b>\frac12-a $. Bob's chances will then amount to $\approx \frac{b-a}2<\frac{1-a}3$. Even with small $a$, this is worse than the *at least* $\frac{a1-a}3$ Bob achieves without such a coalition.

In the end, Alice can guarantee only $\approx\frac14$.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer Hagen. I think you might have over-complicated the problem though. Actually the scenario I intended in my original question is such that they cannot communicate with each other so there are no agreements or coalitions.

Comment: I think some optimal strategies for Alice still exist even if we rule out communications. For example, so WLOG suppose Alice chooses $a<1/2$, then Bob simply *won't* choose $b<a$ because then as you proved Carol will be strictly better off than Bob which Bob won't like. So Alice actually doesn't have to "persuade" Bob to choose $b>a$, because Bob *must* do so anyway.

Comment: What I got, when coalition isn't allowed, is Alice will choose $a<1/2$ yet as close to $1/2$ as possible - actually Bob and Carol will get equal probs as a result of equilibrium (suppose Bob chooses $b\in (a, 1/2)$, then Carol gets $\max(1-b, (b-a)/2)$ by placing either immediately left or right to Bob, and Bob gets $\min(1-b, (b-a)/2)$, so in equilibrium they must equal since Bob chooses before Carol), and the prob Alice gets is $(1+2a)/3$, therefore to ensure a superior probability, Alice just has to choose any $a\in (0, 1/2)$. Or, by symmetry, any $a\ne 1/2$.