# Optimal Strategy for a betting game.

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, expected-value, game-theory

I shall present my question and then add some of the working I have tried, unfortunately I haven't had much luck so far.

**The game**
The game is played between $3$ players. You and $2$ opponents who we shall call $I$ and $R$ (for intelligent and random) You each select an integer from $1-100$ (inclusive) and then money is exchanged as follows:

Whoever selected the Largest number is the looser, they must pay the two winners what they each selected.

Example: You pick $42$, $I$ picks $12$ and $R$ picks $51$ then $R$ must pay you $\$42$ and he must pay $I$ $\$12$

In the event of a two or more players selecting the largest number then a looser is selected uniformly between them.

$R$ plays uniformly randomly, that is he selects his pick uniformly between the first $100$ integers.  
$I$ Plays perfectly to maximise their own E.V (all standard game theory assumptions)

What should your strategy be to maximise your expected value?

**My workings so far:**

For what it is worth in the 2 player scenario where it is just you v.s $R$ then you should pick $33$ as 
$\mathbb{E}[\delta_x ] = \frac{100-x}{100}(x) - \frac{x-1}{100}(-\frac{x}{2})$

(where $\delta_x$ is the strategy of picking $x$) 
This function is maximised at $33$ from simple calculus.

No the answer is not $1$ as picking $2$ performs much better when you know someone is picking $1$

I asked my teacher and they said a mixed strategy but I am struggling with formulating this.

My idea was to determine $f(x,y) = \mathbb{E}[\delta_x | \text{other player is picking y } ]$ and then find the maxima of this function but I am struggling.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick the closest number game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840442/pick-the-closest-number-game)

Comment: It isn't the same game. In the game you link there are not payments. 0 could be a solution in that game if the random number is 0, but in this, if you pick 0, your payment if you win will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

I answered (or at least tried) a question similar to this.The game was the same. [Optimal strategy in three-player number-picking game](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3411680)